# What is numpy.rollaxis doing?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(8)    
a=a.reshape(2,2,2)
print(a)
```

I can understand the answer is:

```
  [[[0 1]
      [2 3]]
     [[4 5]
      [6 7]]]
```

but when print(np.rollaxis(a,2)), I can't understand the answer:

```
 [[[0 2]
      [4 6]]
     [[1 3]
      [5 7]]]
```

and when print(np.rollaxis(a,2,1)),I can't understand the answer too:

```
 [[[0 2]
      [1 3]]
     [[4 6]
      [5 7]]]
```

What is the process of these rollaxis?

Comment: You're not testing this on an array that's easy to see what's going on.  Try one without the same shape in each axis.  Also you should be using `moveaxis` over `rollaxis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it hard on yourself by using an array with the same size along every axis, so it's difficult to see the transformation that `rollaxis` is performing.  It is much easier to understand this operation on an array with varying sizes along each axis.

---

Here is a better example:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2,1)
```

`rollaxis` takes the axis you specify, and moves it to a given position (default value is 0):

```
>>> a.shape
(4, 2, 1)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 1).shape               # Rolls axis 1 to position 0
(2, 4, 1)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 2).shape               # Rolls axis 2 to position 0
(1, 4, 2)
```

---

While this function is still supported, best practice is to use [`numpy.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis), which behaves similarly, but does not have a default argument for the destination of an axis:

```
>>> np.moveaxis(a, 2).shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-77b5e96d3a20> in <module>()
----> 1 np.moveaxis(a, 2).shape

TypeError: moveaxis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'destination'

>>> np.moveaxis(a, 2, 0).shape
(1, 4, 2)
```